# How can I post an image as a link in the 'About me' section of the profile on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, profile-page, network-profile

I am changing the *About me* section in my Stack Overflow profile. I want to post an image as a link in it, so that when the user clicks on it, it should be redirected to my link.

I’m looking for something similar what this user has done:

[image]

When you click on the <kbd>Buy me a coffee</kbd> button, it redirects to his page.

User profile link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501279/guru-stron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "About me" section uses the same Markdown editor as regular SE posts.

You can [write Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) there yourself, or use the GUI buttons in the ribbon above the text area to embed links and images.

To answer the question directly, this is the Markdown syntax you can use:

```
[![Image description][1]](https://link/to/somewhere)

  [1]: https://link/to/your/image.jpg
```